# Regex for matching, except two words. In Nginx server

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to create 3 servers in Nginx

one which can match everything EXCEPT if the name contains `-testing` or `-staging`.

one which matches everything with `-testing` in the server_name.
one which matches everything with `-staging` in the server_name.

The last two are not the problem. Those are working. I'm just struggling with the first.

Here is the regex i tried:
`~^.*(?!(-testing)|(-staging))\.example\.lh$`

https://regex101.com/r/m8vXsL/1 (removed the tilde)

But it still matches server_names containing those words. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if `nginx` supports it (you've chosen pcre in your example, so assume so), just insert a `<` to get  negative look-behind instead. I.e `^.*(?<!(-testing)|(-staging))\.example\.lh$`

Comment: That worked perfectly. Yes nginx supports pcre. `The regular expressions used by nginx are compatible with those used by the Perl programming language (PCRE). To use a regular expression, the server name must start with the tilde character:`

Comment: If you mean the `-testing` and `-staging` cannot appear *anywhere*, not just immediately before `.example.lh`, you may use a lookahead check - [`^(?!.*-(?:testing|staging)).*\.example\.lh$`](https://regex101.com/r/cPGIQE/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that would have been acceptable as well. Thank you. And saves me on the duplicate `-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `nginx` supports it (you've chosen pcre in your example, so assume so), just insert a `<` to get negative look-behind instead. I.e

```
^.*(?<!(-testing)|(-staging))\.example\.lh$
     ^
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/m8vXsL/3).